# How does KafkaStreams determine whether a GlobalKTable is fully populated while bootstrapping?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

The topic I use to create a GlobalKTable is very active. In the documentation of [KStream-GlobalKTable join](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-globalktable-join) I read

> The `GlobalKTable` is fully bootstrapped upon (re)start of a `KafkaStreams` instance, which means the table is fully populated with all the data in the underlying topic that is available at the time of the startup. The actual data processing begins only once the bootstrapping has completed.

**How does KafkaStreams determine whether all data is read?** Does it read all the messages with a timestamp below the `KafkaStreams` instance bootstrap time? Or does it use some kind of timeout?

Either way, I guess we better get the *retention* and *log compaction* of the underlying topic right or a restart might take a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On startup, Kafka Streams reads the current log-end-offsets and bootstrapping is finished after all those data was loaded (cf. [KIP-99](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-99%3A+Add+Global+Tables+to+Kafka+Streams)).

Note, `GlobalKTable` is designed with static/rarely changing data in mind.

> Either way, I guess we better get the retention and log compaction of the underlying topic right or a restart might take a while.

`GlobalKTable` [checkpoints as of 0.11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5241) (released today) so bootstrapping should be much faster on restart than in 0.10.2.